# Loop through a table, pass results to a html table for emailing?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, scripting

So I have a table that tracks "outstanding requests" for users with thousands of entries within. One user may have many outstanding requests. I am looking for the best way to loop through this table and pass the outstanding requests for each user to a html formatted table so that I can ultimately send ONE email to each user with their outstanding requests. Is this achievable ?

For example; If I was a user on the system and I had 7 outstanding requests. I would get one email with my 7 requests highlighted in a table..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where are you sending the emails from? SQL Server, a mail merge application, something else? What have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck or why isn't it working?

Comment: This is a broad question and not a specific coding problem. There are many ways to tackle this problem depending on your requirements. Does this have to be 100% T-SQL (sending customer emails is not what it is designed for), can there be other scripting languages like PowerShell, will this be a periodic task that needs an automatic schedule, ...? Please show use your personal attempt where we can start from.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments have mentioned, the question is quite broad and the approach I have provided is not exactly a good standard to work by but I have chosen to answer to suit the title.

I have attached some code that will select from a SQL table into a temporary table, Then loop through that table building up a HTML table from tags which will then need to be passed to a service to send the email.

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE result
    (id int,
    header nvarchar(255));
    
INSERT INTO result
    values(1, 'hey'), (2, 'this' ), (3, 'is' ), (4, 'a' ), (5, 'row' );
```

SQL

```
Declare @Id int
Declare @Header nvarchar(255)
Declare @EmailString nvarchar(max)

select id, header into #tmpResult from result
 Set @EmailString = IsNull(@EmailString,'') +   
'  
<table style="width:100%;background-color:#000000;">  
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff">  
    <th>Id</th>  
    <th>Header</th>   
</tr>  
'  
 While Exists (Select * from #tmpResult)  
 Begin  
               
   SELECT Top 1   
   @Id = id,  
   @Header = header              
   from #tmpResult
               
   Select @EmailString = @EmailString
   +  
   '<tr bgcolor="#ffffff"><td>' 
   + 
   Cast(@Id as nvarchar(max))   
   +   
   '</td><td>'   
   +        
   @Header  
   +
   '</td></tr>'  
               
   Delete from #tmpResult where Id = @Id  
               
 End  
 Drop table #tmpResult  
  
  
 Set @EmailString = @EmailString + '</table>'  
  
               
select @EmailString
```

I hope this goes some way to solving your issue.

Chris